# HOW TO INSTALL postgreSQL 10.15 version on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, postgresql

I want to install PostgreSQL 10.15 version on my ubuntu device,

referred below link and tried installing the same but it shows error:
https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-10.15
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-10.15'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-10.15'
```

for below command

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-10.15
```

or for below command

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql=10.15
```

i get below error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '10.15' for 'postgresql' was not found
```

Please help, its urgent, need to install and investigate an issue.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `apt-cache madison postgresql` to see what versions of Postgresql are available in the Ubuntu repositories for your release of Ubuntu. The Ubuntu repositories do **not** contain an infinite series of built packages for all possible versions.

Comment: postgresql | 14+242.pgdg20.04+1 | http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg/main amd64 Packages
postgresql | 12+214ubuntu0.1 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
postgresql | 12+214ubuntu0.1 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
postgresql | 12+214ubuntu0.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
postgresql | 12+214ubuntu0.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages

Comment: postgresql |12+214 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
postgresql |12+214 | http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages

Here is a response @user535733

Comment: Well, the point was for YOU to see that output, showing you exactly why you are getting the error message. Your options are to install a release of Ubuntu that does have 10.15 available, or to build your desired 10.15 from source. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423934/edit) to clarify which kinds of solutions you are open to.

Comment: @user535733, I want to install PostgreSQL 10.15 as I need to investigate an error that we received while on release, 

actually, I want to recreate the error received that we received while on release. hence i want to setup the same environment locally to recreate the issue.

i have installed flyway but struggling to install postgresql 10.15 version, please help.

Comment: If you need a *very specific version* of software, the only realistic way to accomplish the goal is to use Docker containers. [There are two](https://hub.docker.com/r/amd64/postgres/tags?page=1&name=10.15) options available for PostgreSQL 10.15 on Docker Hub 